# Various definitions of coercivity

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, hilbert-spaces, nonlinear-optimization

In [this post](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Babuska-Lax-Milgram_theorem) one says that a functional $F:H\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space $H$ is *(strongly) coercive* if there exists a constant $k>0$ such that
$$
F(x)\geq k\|x\|_H^2.
$$

However, the definition I'm familiar with (set on an arbitrary topological space $X$) requires that $F:X\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ satisfy the following:  For every $t>0$ the set $\{x \in X:\, F(x)\leq r\}$ has compact-closure.

So when applying this definition to the case where $X=H$, shouldn't $F$ only be coercive in the weak topology?

Comment: On an arbitrary topological space, you do not have a notion of a "bounded" set. I think that is why sets of compact closure were used instead.

Comment: That makes sense but are the two notions at-least equivalent when $X=H$?

Comment: No, of course not.